# How to implement abstract polymorphism / disjoint polymorphism in Rust?

Tags: rust

Here is the specific problem. Suppose I want to difine a `Divides` trait for numbers, in which a method `divides` should be implemented to examine if divisibility relationship holds for two numbers.

```
pub trait Divides {
    fn divides(&self, &other: Self) -> bool;
}
```

For intergers, this is down by testing if the remainder is zero, while for real numbers, the divisibility relationship always holds unless the divisor is zero. What I want is as follows:

```
trait Integer: Rem {}
trait Real: Div {}
impl Integer for i8 {}
impl Integer for i16 {}
...
impl Integer for i128 {}
...
impl Integer for u128 {}
impl Real for f32 {}
impl Real for f64 {}

impl <T:Integer> Divides for T {
    fn divides(&self, &other: Self) -> bool {
        self % other == 0
    }
}

impl <T:Real> Divides for T {
    fn divides(&self, &other: Self) -> bool {
        self == 0 || other != 0
    }
}
```

The compiler will then tell me "error: conflicting implementations of trait `Divides`".
I understand that the Rust compiler does not support such things. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, rust doesn't support it because, in theory, there could be a type that implements both `Integer` and `Real`, in which case there would be conflict. There are ways you can implement the functionality, but they might not suit your needs and they have their drawbacks. Two approaches come to mind:

1. You could have `DividesInteger` and `DividesReal` traits.

```rust
pub trait DividesInteger {
    fn divides(&self, other: &Self) -> bool;
}
pub trait DividesReal {
    fn divides(&self, other: &Self) -> bool;
}

impl<T> DividesInteger for T where T: Integer {/*...*/}
impl<T> DividesReal for T where T: Real {/*...*/}
```

2. You could wrap numeric types in an enum. The disadvantage is that it requires boxing.

```rust
enum Number {
    Integer(Box<dyn Integer>),
    Real(Box<dyn Real>),
}

impl Divides for Number {
    fn divides(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        match self {
            Number::Integer(num) => num & other == 0,
            Number::Real(num) => num == 0 || other != 0,
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, that assumes that the traits require all the necessary operations for the implementation.

My recommendation is that you implement it for each type separately. You could use macros for that.
[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5fc5b5b0dce5ca1048663489f43eee3a)